# Any issues with tearing down this closet to open up some space in our mudroom?

Tags: load-bearing, closet, demolition

we are wanting to take down this closet, and put in some custom locker cabinets instead for our mudroom entry since it is pretty cramped.

First and most important, I assume this wall isn't load bearing. There is a bedroom above, and open basement below. There is a bathroom behind the back wall of the closet so just need to be careful for pipes there. There is also the light switch on the closet wall, which I was just planning to relocate next to the door on the back wall.

Anything I should watch out for or is this pretty straightforward? Take down the outer closet walls, move the light switch, patch the drywall, and the ceiling, along with adding popcorn texture to match the rest.

[image]

Comment: It could be pretty straight forward or end up being the closet removal from hell.  Too early to tell.  Matching popcorn ceilings are never easy.

Comment: Fixing the missing floor patches and ceiling texture doesn't sound fun. You can't just remove the door and casing, wrap the wall ends with drywall, and build your locker cabinets in the walled space?

Comment: Removing the closet should be easy.  Matching the patches to the rest is the very hard part.  Might be a hybrid way of keeping some of the closet(top/some ends) with the lockers.